# Optional arguments in a function

Tags: python

I'm writing a python script to find restrictionplaces. I was wondering if there is a better way to write the following:

```
def restrictionplace(string, minLength = '', maxLength = ''):
    if minLength == '': minLength = 4
    if maxLength == '': maxLength = 12

    #rest of script
```

if there is no min or maxlength given, the script should use 4 or 12.

Answer (score 14):

Python lets you set default values for parameters in the method signature in the way you have done above with `minLength=''`. This means that if the caller of the function doesn't provide a value for that parameter the default of an empty string will be used instead. Essentially doing the job of your `if minLength == '': minLength = 4` line. Here is what you might write instead:

```
def restriction_place(string, min_length=4, max_length=12):
    pass
```

I also took the liberty of using snake_case as that's the convention in Python for variable and function names (in most cases).

There is a caveat to default values when using mutables, however. see: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/

Comment: Didn't know this was also possible to be honest, quite new to programming :)! Thanks.

Comment: No problem. I'll update my answer and explain it a little better. There is a caveat to doing this.

Answer (score 3):

While freebie's answer works (and is a very common solution to this problem), I prefer an alternate approach that using `None` and `or` chaining:

```
def restriction_place(string, min_length=None, max_length=None):
    min_length = min_length or 4
    max_length = max_length or 12
    assert min_length <= max_length

    # do actual work
```

This works because the `or` operator in Python returns its left hand side if it is [truthy](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/295354/why-does-presence-of-value-evaluate-as-truthy-in-python-e-i-types-evaluate), and otherwise returns its right hand side. Since `None` is falsy in Python, when the arguments are left as their defaults, these expressions replace them with their "true" default values.

The advantage to this is that callers to the function never have to know what a "default" value should be for an argument; if they want to default it, they can pass it as `None`. This is useful for example when writing wrapper functions:

```
def wrapped_restriction_place(string, min_length=None, max_length=None):
    # we've decided that in our wrapper, we want to clean our strings up first
    string = string.strip()

    # now we call the original function!
    restriction_place(string, min_length, max_length)
```

The advantage here is that using "true" default arguments, the wrapper function would either have to know the defaults that the base function uses for its arguments (which makes it easy to break the code accidentally by changing the default arguments in the base class), or it would have to branch to omit the arguments entirely when they weren't specified.

Comment: This will fail if you want to pass `min_length=0` to this function, because it will evaluate as `False` and will be set to 4.

Comment: @Graipher True. Unfortunately, I don't think Python provides any elegant way of handling those case without extra branching (which is that the OP already has in his original post).